# Replace a <div> tag to <h2> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a lot of html files and I need to replace all the `span` or `div` tags with a specific atribute `class` to a `h3` tag.

For example,

Before:

```
<div class="style1"> Text </div>

<span class="style1"> Text2 </span>
```

After:

```
<h3> Text </h3>

<h3> Text2 </h3>
```

How can I do this using BeautifulSoup library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the name property of a Tag to change it:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup("<div>text</div>")
bs.find("div").name = "h2"

print bs # "<h2>text</h2>"
```